# Pass a reference of string from C# to C++ function

Tags: c#, c++, mfc

I have a C++ library and I wrote some functions in it.
this function must return an integer and a string. (2 outputs) and I'm going to call this function from my C# Program.
here is my code in C++:

```
extern "C"{

    __declspec(dllexport)   UINT Read(OUT char* Temp )
    {
    .....
    }  
}
```

and it's my C# code in `ImportDll` class:

```
[DllImport("Library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint Read(char[] temp);
```

and in my form I have this:

```
char[] str = new char[256];  
ImportDLL.Read(str);
```

it returns an Int correctly but the string result (str array) is totally zero (\0)!
what is wrong with my code?
thank you.

Comment: Why use char[], You can use string.

Comment: If you have code of dll then you can debug the "Read" function and see that what is happening inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One addition to the answer from Matthew Watson: you would also need to marshal the stringbuilder parameter to LPSTR (char *), like

```
[DllImport("Library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint Read([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the returned value is an OUT, I'm assuming that it is created by the C++ method.

In this case, you might need to pass a StringBuilder to it:

```
[DllImport("Library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint Read(StringBuilder temp);
```

Note that you should also specify the charset, which depends on the character encoding that your C++ code is using - ANSI or Unicode.

To call it, create a new StringBuilder of sufficient size and pass it to `Read()`, and then use StringBuilder.ToString() to retrieve the string after `Read()` returns.

If the C++ function expects a string buffer of a certain size, you need to create the StringBuilder to be at least that size, e.g.:

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 128;
var sb = new StringBuilder(BUFFER_SIZE);
Read(sb);
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Note: It's hard to say if this is really the right solution without knowing the details of the C++ function. It might be that you just need to pass a string.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was helpful but the correct answer is this: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder temp